# Reset back route in React Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I am using React Navigation v5 in a React Native project.

I have a Stack navigator set up with 3 screens, eg:

Screen A, Screen B, Screen C

Screen A is the Home screen, Screen B has a Back button in the header which should always go back to Screen A. But there are 2 ways we can get to Screen B:

1. Screen A > Screen B
2. Screen A > Screen C > Screen B

If we get to Screen B via Screen C, is there a way I can reset the route history to the Back button will go back to Screen A (rather than Screen C).

I've had a look into the reset method but that navigates back to Screen A immediately rather than altering the route history.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom header for screen c and put an icon there and pass this function to that icon like this:

```
<Icon onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Screen A')} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wanted to avoid messing with the header icons. Anyway, I ended up refactoring my navigation to achieve what I wanted which I think is probably the better way to do it rather than altering history states.